# How to print uint8 in decimal?

Tags: c

I want to print the output value of an instruction in decimal. I made different instruction. But I have different results from my code. So, I am not sure if it is correct or not. I don't know the initial value to make the comparaison and check to right way:

```
uint16_t id;
id |= *((uint8_t*)(pkt->payload)+ptr)<<8;
printf("t_id %u\n", (unsigned int)id);
```

Comment: You're using `|=` when `id` is not initialized.

Comment: @dbush I would be very grateful if you could develop your answer. I am not so familar with c language

Answer (score 1):

You're reading from `id` which is uninitialized.

The `|=` operator performs a bitwise OR of the left and right operands and stores the result in the left operand.  That means this:

```
x |= y;
```

Is the same as:

```
x = x | y;
```

In your code, you have `id` as the left side of the `|=` operator, but you never initialized `id`.  That means you're reading an uninitialized value.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to either initialize `id` with some known value or simply use `=` instead of `|=`.